# Creating tabs using HTML and loading different content, for click of each tab

Tags: html, tabs

I need to create tabs on the webpage using html, and on click of each tab, need to load different content on the same page. Do let me know how to go about this, or any useful links that might help me.

Thanks,
Geetha

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with jQuery and jQuery UI.

Here you can find some information about it. http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/

Answer (score 1):

Dojo (javascript framework) has a TabContainer. It's easy to implement, but depends on the content and how do you want to present it to the user.

You can start by looking here: [Dojo TabContainer info](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer)

There's an example on that site which lets you see the html and javascript required to build a tabbed container.